# JavaMail and Gmail: first attempt results in "Remote host closed connection during handshake" but after next attempt everything works

Tags: email, java-8, gmail, jakarta-mail, wildfly

I am trying to send emails using Java web application. I use Java 8, Spring 4 and Wildfly 9.2 server for my app. The environment is set on my local machine. The problem is that when I run my code for the first time, it returns the following exception:

> javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not convert socket to TLS;
>     nested exception is:
>       javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake

but all next attempts result in success, an email is sent. I use following code:

```
try {
    String user = "user";
    String password = "password";
    String emailAddress = "to@gmail.com"
    Properties emailProperties = new Properties();
    emailProperties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
    emailProperties.setProperty("mail.smtp.port", "587");
    emailProperties.setProperty("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    emailProperties.setProperty("mail.smtp.debug", "true");
    emailProperties.setProperty("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    emailProperties.setProperty("mail.smtp.ssl.trust", "smtp.gmail.com");

    Authenticator auth = new Authenticator() {
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication(user, password);
        }
    };

    Session session = Session.getInstance(emailProperties, auth);
    session.setDebug(true);

    MimeMessage email = new MimeMessage(session);
    email.setFrom(new InternetAddress(user));
    email.addRecipient(javax.mail.Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(emailAddress));
    email.setSubject("Subject");
    email.setContent("Content", "text/html");
    Transport.send(email);
} catch (MessagingException e) {
    LOG.error("Email was not sent: {}", e.getMessage());
}
```

Do you know why this may happen? This is a debug log from the first attempt:

```
12:49:32,981 DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle,1.5.3]
12:49:33,078 DEBUG SMTP: need username and password for authentication
12:49:33,078 DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
12:49:33,079 DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "smtp.gmail.com", port 587, isSSL false
12:49:33,159 220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP gk6sm22113963wjc.21 - gsmtp
12:49:33,159 DEBUG SMTP: connected to host "smtp.gmail.com", port: 587
12:49:33,159 
12:49:43,166 EHLO 192.168.0.104
12:49:43,200 250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [178.235.6.245]
12:49:43,200 250-SIZE 35882577
12:49:43,200 250-8BITMIME
12:49:43,200 250-STARTTLS
12:49:43,200 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
12:49:43,201 250-PIPELINING
12:49:43,201 250-CHUNKING
12:49:43,201 250 SMTPUTF8
12:49:43,201 DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SIZE", arg "35882577"
12:49:43,201 DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "8BITMIME", arg ""
12:49:43,201 DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "STARTTLS", arg ""
12:49:43,202 DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES", arg ""
12:49:43,202 DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "PIPELINING", arg ""
12:49:43,202 DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "CHUNKING", arg ""
12:49:43,202 DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SMTPUTF8", arg ""
12:49:43,202 STARTTLS
12:49:43,245 220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS
12:50:35,603 ERROR c.f.s.services.utility.EmailSender - Email was not sent: Could not convert socket to TLS
```

and this is a debug log from next attempts:

```
13:17:19,466 DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle,1.5.3]
13:17:19,489 DEBUG SMTP: need username and password for authentication
13:17:19,489 DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
13:17:19,489 DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "smtp.gmail.com", port 587, isSSL false
13:17:19,556 220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP 18sm29785121wmr.5 - gsmtp
13:17:19,556 DEBUG SMTP: connected to host "smtp.gmail.com", port: 587
13:17:19,556 
13:17:29,621 EHLO 192.168.0.104
13:17:29,664 250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [178.235.6.245]
13:17:29,664 250-SIZE 35882577
13:17:29,665 250-8BITMIME
13:17:29,665 250-STARTTLS
13:17:29,665 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
13:17:29,665 250-PIPELINING
13:17:29,665 250-CHUNKING
13:17:29,665 250 SMTPUTF8
13:17:29,665 DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SIZE", arg "35882577"
13:17:29,665 DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "8BITMIME", arg ""
13:17:29,665 DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "STARTTLS", arg ""
13:17:29,666 DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES", arg ""
13:17:29,666 DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "PIPELINING", arg ""
13:17:29,666 DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "CHUNKING", arg ""
13:17:29,666 DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SMTPUTF8", arg ""
13:17:29,666 STARTTLS
13:17:29,714 220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS
13:17:29,891 EHLO 192.168.0.104
13:17:29,927 250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [178.235.6.245]
13:17:29,927 250-SIZE 35882577
13:17:29,927 250-8BITMIME
13:17:29,927 250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER XOAUTH
13:17:29,927 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
13:17:29,927 250-PIPELINING
13:17:29,927 250-CHUNKING
13:17:29,927 250 SMTPUTF8
13:17:29,928 DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SIZE", arg "35882577"
13:17:29,928 DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "8BITMIME", arg ""
13:17:29,928 DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "AUTH", arg "LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER XOAUTH"
13:17:29,928 DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES", arg ""
13:17:29,928 DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "PIPELINING", arg ""
13:17:29,928 DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "CHUNKING", arg ""
13:17:29,928 DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SMTPUTF8", arg ""
13:17:29,928 DEBUG SMTP: Attempt to authenticate using mechanisms: LOGIN PLAIN DIGEST-MD5 NTLM 
13:17:29,928 DEBUG SMTP: AUTH LOGIN command trace suppressed
13:17:30,220 DEBUG SMTP: AUTH LOGIN succeeded
13:17:30,221 DEBUG SMTP: use8bit false
13:17:30,221 MAIL FROM:<from@gmail.com>
13:17:30,255 250 2.1.0 OK 18sm29785121wmr.5 - gsmtp
13:17:30,255 RCPT TO:<to@gmail.com>
13:17:30,285 250 2.1.5 OK 18sm29785121wmr.5 - gsmtp
13:17:30,285 DEBUG SMTP: Verified Addresses
13:17:30,285 DEBUG SMTP:   to@gmail.com
13:17:30,285 DATA
13:17:30,455 354  Go ahead 18sm29785121wmr.5 - gsmtp
13:17:30,455 From: from@gmail.com
13:17:30,455 To: to@gmail.com
13:17:30,456 Message-ID: <16429346.2.1479039439466@Mac-mini-Jacek.local>
13:17:30,456 Subject: Subject
13:17:30,456 MIME-Version: 1.0
13:17:30,456 Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii
13:17:30,456 Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
13:17:30,456 
13:17:30,456 Content
13:17:30,456 .
13:17:30,958 250 2.0.0 OK 1479039450 18sm29785121wmr.5 - gsmtp
13:17:30,958 DEBUG SMTP: message successfully delivered to mail server
13:17:30,958 QUIT
13:17:30,993 221 2.0.0 closing connection 18sm29785121wmr.5 - gsmtp
```

UPDATE

After adding javax.net.debug=ssl I see this during the first attempt the following lines:

```
21:04:29,655 INFO trustStore is: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_91.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/security/cacerts
21:04:29,656 trustStore type is : jks
21:04:29,656 trustStore provider is : 
21:04:29,656 init truststore
21:04:29,727 adding as trusted cert:
a very long list of "adding as trusted cert:"
21:04:29,794 trigger seeding of SecureRandom
21:04:29,794 done seeding SecureRandom
21:04:39,903 Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
21:04:39,935 Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
21:04:39,997 Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
21:04:39,997 Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
21:04:39,997 Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
21:04:39,997 Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
21:04:39,997 Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
21:04:39,997 Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
21:04:39,997 Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
21:04:39,997 Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
21:04:39,997 Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
21:04:39,997 Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
21:04:39,997 Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
21:04:39,997 Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
21:04:39,998 Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
21:04:39,998 Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
21:04:39,998 Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
21:04:39,998 Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
21:04:39,998 Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
21:04:39,998 Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
21:04:39,998 Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
21:04:40,007 Allow unsafe renegotiation: false
21:04:40,007 Allow legacy hello messages: true
21:04:40,007 Is initial handshake: true
21:04:40,007 Is secure renegotiation: false
21:04:40,007 Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
21:04:40,008 Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
21:04:40,008 Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
21:04:40,008 Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
21:04:40,008 Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
21:04:40,008 Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
21:04:40,008 Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
21:04:40,008 Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
21:04:40,008 Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
21:04:40,008 Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
21:04:40,008 Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
21:04:40,008 Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
21:04:40,008 Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
21:04:40,009 Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
21:04:40,011 %% No cached client session
21:04:40,014 *** ClientHello, TLSv1.2
21:04:40,015 RandomCookie:  GMT: 1479260888 bytes = { 36, 201, 224, 18, 161, 111, 128, 63, 52, 24, 49, 83, 212, 131, 233, 146, 53, 84, 44, 138, 116, 131, 28, 55, 75, 36, 44, 170 }
21:04:40,015 Session ID:  {}
21:04:40,016 Cipher Suites: [TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]
21:04:40,017 Compression Methods:  { 0 }
21:04:40,018 Extension elliptic_curves, curve names: {secp256r1, sect163k1, sect163r2, secp192r1, secp224r1, sect233k1, sect233r1, sect283k1, sect283r1, secp384r1, sect409k1, sect409r1, secp521r1, sect571k1, sect571r1, secp160k1, secp160r1, secp160r2, sect163r1, secp192k1, sect193r1, sect193r2, secp224k1, sect239k1, secp256k1}
21:04:40,018 Extension ec_point_formats, formats: [uncompressed]
21:04:40,019 Extension signature_algorithms, signature_algorithms: SHA512withECDSA, SHA512withRSA, SHA384withECDSA, SHA384withRSA, SHA256withECDSA, SHA256withRSA, SHA224withECDSA, SHA224withRSA, SHA1withECDSA, SHA1withRSA, SHA1withDSA
21:04:40,019 Extension server_name, server_name: [type=host_name (0), value=smtp.gmail.com]
21:04:40,019 ***
21:04:40,019 default task-1, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 216
21:04:40,020 default task-1, received EOFException: error
21:04:40,020 default task-1, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
21:04:40,022 default task-1, SEND TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, description = handshake_failure
21:04:40,022 default task-1, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2
21:04:40,022 default task-1, called closeSocket()
```

and every next attempt has this:

```
21:20:03,114 default task-2, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 216
21:20:03,149 default task-2, READ: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 91
21:20:03,150 *** ServerHello, TLSv1.2
many other lines
```

Comment: Try setting the [System property javax.net.debug to "ssl"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html#Debug), the debug output may provide more clues about why it's not working.

Comment: Please check my initial question. I updated it with the additional logging.